# g++: expected primary-expression before ‘[’ token

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to find if all the elements of a vector y is equal to 1. The following code works fine in Visual Studio but with g++ in linux (g++ -std=c++0x) it gives me this error: expected primary-expression before ‘[’ token

```
bool x = all_of(y.begin(), y.end(), [](unsigned char j) {return j == 1;});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

My gcc version is: `g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)`

Comment: What version of g++ are you using?

Comment: Are you sure you enabled c++11? Or perhaps you have an ancient version of g++.

Comment: `-std=c++0x` This suggests an old compiler. What version of GCC is that?

Comment: g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)

Comment: Well there you go then! (Please add that important detail to the question)

Comment: @Ali That's almost five years old. Time to upgrade.

Comment: Thanks guys. It is a school machine so I am not sure if I can upgrade it. Is there any other workaround?

Comment: Use an actual function/function pointer

Comment: Yeah, use a functor instead. i.e. the old-fashioned way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambdas are not supported in GCC 4.4. You can upgrade your compiler to version 4.5 or above, or use a function:

```
bool compFun(int i) {
    return i == 1;
}
...
bool res = all_of(a.begin(), a.end(), compFun);
```

[Here is a live example.](http://ideone.com/ljs7vb)

Answer (score 3):

[Lambdas are not supported in GCC 4.4](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/cxx0x_status.html).

Upgrade your compiler. You need GCC 4.5 or higher, but get to modern times if you can.

Comment: @GillBates you mock, but Turbo C++ is coming back, man. Just like Disco.

Answer (score 2):

Your compiler not support lambda expression. Compilers do not support all features that come with C++11 or new incoming standards. Therefore you need to check which standards the compiler supports.
[image: Screenshot of compilation on GCC 4.4.7]

You can see if I select gcc-4.4.7 same error( lambda expression error) but if I select gcc-4.5.3

[image: Screenshot of compilation on GCC 4.5.2]

No error. In summary, You have to change your compiler( >= gcc-4.5 ) to use lamda expression.

[image: C++ Standards Support in GCC]